# Possible causes for php string with ISO 8601 date conversion adds one more hour

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime, iso8601

Basically I've got this:

```
$data_start = '2012-06-07T13:00:00Z';

if (($timestamp = strtotime($data_start)) === false) {
    return "The string ($data_start) is bogus";
} else {
    return "$data_start == " . date('l dS \o\f F Y H:i:s', $timestamp);
}
```

And it is returning:

```
"Thursday 07th of June 2012 14:00:00"
```

Why on earth is strtotime adding 1 more hour!? Anything to do with timezones?

Comment: Z stands for Zulu which stands for Zulu Time which is UTC / GMT. And that is related to timezones, because timezones are related to UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the last Z on $data_start tells that the date is in UTC time.
I suppose your local timezone is UTC +1 ?

if you want to always work with UTC time, you can use something like : date_default_timezone_set ('UTC') to bypass your local timezone setting

Comment: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=133 it says lisbon timezone is UTC+1

Comment: true... but that's because of daylight saving time... what a confusion! What about winter, when we move back again to +00 ?

Comment: yes, you can use date('Z') to get your timezone offset in seconds.

Comment: The problem is, I have that string in ISO 8601 and it always come in that format. So in my code, I need to check if i'm in DST (summer time) or not ? There is no straight formward way to do it ?

Comment: i don't understand why you need to know if its DST or not ?

Comment: Well basically, i have that string with date `$data_start` that I can't change its format. And then I need to convert it to a normal PHP date, but in the summer i'm getting the wrong time, as showed in my example above. How to solve it ?

Comment: your not getting the wrong time, '2012-06-07T13:00:00Z' = "Thursday 07th of June 2012 14:00:00"
 in lisbon

Comment: if you want to always work with UTC time, you can use something like : date_default_timezone_set ('UTC') to bypass your local timezone setting

Comment: +1 for that. Update your answer please, with that last note because I believe it's usefull for future readers. Thanks nico